# CakePHP view variable as datetime instead of string

Tags: string, cakephp, variables, datetime

In my AppController beforeFilter i am saving user data to variables for use in my view. I need to grab the last_login field that is a datetime and then use the dateformat function to display the date i want but cakephp is outputting this variable as a string, is there a way to putput as the format of the table? (datetime).

```
        // Set user variables for each page load
        $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        // Set $id
        $user_data = $this->User->findById($id);
        // Set User Last Login
        $user_lastlogin = $user_data['User']['last_login'];
        $this->set('lastLogin', $user_lastlogin);
```

View

```
<?php echo date_format($lastLogin, 'F jS \at h:i:s A'); ?>
```

Error

```
Warning (2): date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your code is messy. Try this:

```
$this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$this->set('lastLogin', $this->User->field('last_login'));
```

Cake has [a class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html) for doing dates and times.

```
echo CakeTime::niceShort($lastLogin);
```

Generally you should do the data to string in the view, making it part of the controller or model will have a negative impact on your application if you need to do other things with the data.